# When is the validator of email uniqueness trigerred?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a question about [this test from the Michael Hartl tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code-validates_uniqueness_of_email_case_insensitive_test) :

**Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
end
```

**Test:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  .
  .
  .
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

My understanding of the uniqueness validator for the email is that it cannot be added twice in the database. But in this test, the User is just instantiated with a new, not a create.

So here is what I think happens:

- `@user = User.new` (just in memory)
- ...
- `user_with_same_email = @user.dup` we have two users in memory
- ...
- `user_with_same_email.save` we are inserting the first user in the db, so it should be valid, and yet the test `it { should_not be_valid }` passes.

What am I getting wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

What really happens:

In `before`:

- `@user = User.new` (just in memory)

In the `describe`:

- `user_with_same_email = @user.dup` we have two users in memory
- `user_with_same_email.save` we are inserting the first user in the db, so it should be valid, and it is ! But that's not what's being tested here

In the `it`:

- `should_not be_valid` calls `.valid?` on @user, and since we've just inserted an user with the same email, @user is not valid. And so the test passes.

Comment: Good answer! It is also important to note that in the case of very quick `INSERT` orders to the DB, they would both pass the validation in memory, hence both would be `INSERT`ed. As discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942608/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-uniqueness-validation